# Proof that $(v^tA^tAu)^2 \leq (u^tA^tAu)(v^tA^tAv)$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

I have a problem. It seems easy, but i have been confused about it. It's given n-by-1 vectors: $u$ and $v$. And dot product is defined as $u\cdot v=v^tu$. Prove that $(v^tA^tAu)^2 \leq (u^tA^tAu)(v^tA^tAv)$.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is a direct application of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) You just have to prove that $\langle u,v \rangle := u^t A^t A v$ is an inner product. It might be worth asking yourself what properties you need $A$ to satisfy.